# array from web content in viewdidload order of operations is weird

Tags: ios, swift

I'm working on a new app which is all about organizing information from web content. It will be a finance app for monitoring the dividend yields of the dow jones. To do this will require a few steps, but I'm working on step one right now. I want to take the 30 companies in the dow jones, look up their current yield, and then rank them according to that number. Right now I'm updating an array to give me the yields of all 30 companies (i.e. [2.7, 3.6, 5.5, 1.3,etc...]). Here is my current code with my question below:

```
let dowDic = ["MMM", "AXP", "AAPL", "BA", "CAT", "CVX", "CSCO", "KO", "DIS", "DD", "XOM", "GE", "GS", "HD", "IBM", "INTC", "JNJ", "JPM", "MCD", "MRK", "MSFT", "NKE", "PFE", "PG", "TRV", "UTX", "UNH", "VZ", "V", "WMT"]

var dowYield = [1.11, 2.11, 3.11, 4.11, 5.11, 6.11, 7.11, 8.11, 9.11, 1.11, 1.11, 2.11, 3.11, 4.11, 5.11, 6.11, 7.11, 8.11, 9.11, 1.11, 1.11, 2.11, 3.11, 4.11, 5.11, 6.11, 7.11, 8.11, 9.11, 1.11]

var counter = 0

@IBOutlet var label: UILabel!


@IBAction func refresh(sender: AnyObject) {

    print(dowYield)

}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.





    print(dowDic.indexOf("WMT"))



    for x in dowDic {

        print(x)

        let url = NSURL(string:"http://finance.yahoo.com/q?s=\(x)")!

        print(url)

        let task = NSURLSession.sharedSession().dataTaskWithURL(url) { (data, response, error) -> Void in

            //will happen after complete

            if let urlContent = data {

                let webContent = NSString(data: urlContent, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)

                let websiteArray = webContent?.componentsSeparatedByString("<th scope=\"row\" width=\"48%\">Div &amp; Yield:</th><td class=\"yfnc_tabledata1\">")

                if websiteArray!.count > 0 {

                    let nextWebsiteArray = websiteArray![1].componentsSeparatedByString(" </td></tr>")

                    if nextWebsiteArray.count > 0 {

                        let websiteSum = nextWebsiteArray[0].componentsSeparatedByString(" (")

                        if websiteSum.count > 0 {

                            let finalYield = websiteSum[1].componentsSeparatedByString("%")

                            let WTF = Double(finalYield[0])

                            print(finalYield[0])



                            self.dowYield[self.counter] = WTF!


                            self.counter++


                        }


                        }

                    }

                }




            }






        task.resume()



    }



    print("flag")

    print(dowYield)




}
```

I want the app to update the array 'dowYield' and access it later in the viewDidLoad, but I can only get the updated print out using a button. The print screen currently prints out the stock symbol and url first, all of them. Then it jumps down to the bottom of the code and prints the 'flag' text and then the original, unedited array of 'dowYield'. Then it one by one prints out the new Yields. Any insight on the order of operations here and how to access the updated array within the viewDidLoad for future operations i want to do with that new information? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how async code works. You start an async job running and it continues on it's own until it's done, some time later.

Think of this as sending somebody off to run an errand for you. The instant after you ask them to run the errand, it still isn't done, and you don't know exactly how long it will take for them to finish. So you go off and do other things, waiting for them to come back and tell you the work is done.

That is what the completion block in your data task is for. It's code that gets saved for later and executed once the data task is finished running. You can be **certain** that that code won't be called until after viewDidLoad exits.

What you want to do is to add a call, *inside the completion block* that uses `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue())` to update your UI on the main thread once the data has been downloaded.

Comment: You should accept my answer if it answers your question. (And once you have enough rep, you should up-vote answers that you find helpful, including answers to others people's questions. Which answers you decide to up-vote is up to you, but you're supposed check the accept button on the first answer that answers your question.)